# Compute the $\vec\nabla^2$ on a simple vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, laplacian

Hey should be a simple check to see if this is correct. I cannot figure out how to enter it into Octave or Wolfram alpha so I need human help :)

Evaluate $\vec\nabla^2 \|\vec x\|^2 $ where $\|\vec x\|^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ and $\vec\nabla = \hat{\imath}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{\jmath}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

I have that $$\vec\nabla \|\vec x\|^2 = 2x\hat i + 2y\hat j + 2z \hat k$$

Then applying the divergence operator (dot product with 'del' or 'nabla') $\vec\nabla\cdot$

$$
\vec\nabla^2 \|\vec x\|^2 = 6
$$
Is that right?
It is surprising me that it is an integer.

Comment: but its not just $\nabla$ it is $\vec\nabla$ it has vector components in it. and when two vectors are multiplied by each other it becomes the sum of their components. The result of $\vec\nabla^2$ should be a scalar.

Comment: Some people use $\nabla^2 f$ to denote the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), that would be $2 I$ for your case. Otherwise, if [$\nabla^2 = \Delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) your computations are correct.

Comment: If you want to know how to get WA to do it, try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplacian+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2).

Comment: @Bye_World, how do i add vector components?

Comment: @Tsangares You mean like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplacian+%7Bx%5E2,y%5E2,z%5E2%7D)?

Comment: @Bye_World, yes that helps quite a bit